# How to mix two numpy arrays using a boolean mask to create one of the same size efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, mask

I use two arrays of the same size like :

```
>>> a = [range(10)]
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b = -a
>>> b
array([ 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9])
```

I want to create another array using a boolean "mask", for example :

```
>>> m = (a % 2 == 0)
>>> m
array([ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Then I create a third array of the same size and change its values for the ones of a if m is True and for the ones of b if m is False :

```
>>> c = ones(10)
>>> c[m] = a[m]
>>> c[~m] = b[~m]
>>> c
array([ 0., -1.,  2., -3.,  4., -5.,  6., -7.,  8., -9.])
```

I wonder if there is a way to do the three last operations (the creation of c) within just one operation (especially for performance optimisation).

The problem of doing :

> > > c = a * m + b * m

is when there are NaN in a or b, when it is multiplied by zero it still makes NaN.

PS : The example I gave would also work for n-dimensionnal arrays.

Comment: There is another possibility :
    >>> c = a
    >>> c[~m] = a[~m]
(~ is the not operator)
But the point is that the these ways of creating c involve one allocation then one modification, I think there could be a way to directly create c as the final form without having to create a matrix and to modify it next.

Comment: Have you tried using `numpy.nan_to_num(a) * m + numpy.nan_to_num(b)*~m`?  `nan_to_num` maps NaN -> 0, +inf -> 1e300, -inf -> -1e300.

Comment: Is that really how you created `a`?  No use of `np.array`?

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
c = numpy.where(m, a, b)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension you could create some conditionals that determine what list to pick form?

```
result = [ a[i] if bol else b[i] for i, bol in enumerate(mask)]
```

And then you could apply some functions to a[i] or b[i] depending on how you want to alter them.

Comment: Yep, it will work, but will not bring the same performance as vectorized selection such as the answer from farenorth I think, especially with large data.

Comment: Oh no doubt, I wasn't thinking of libraries.

Comment: The OP is a bit unclear regarding the use of lists versus numpy arrays.